# Blackberry 10 Dev Alpha update issue

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

I'm having trouble updating the firmware of my Blackberry 10 Dev Aplha B device.

The OS has expired, the message shown is the following: "Thank you for participating. The Blackberry 10 Dev Alpha device program has ended. For details on what to do next, please visit developer.blackberry.com"

I went through the official update tutorial http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/blackberry10devalpha/devalpha_update.html and the behaviour is the same. I've tried some different tutorials that I've found across the web where the main change is to use a different AutoLoader version. I also try to do it without the battery in and still nothing. Once the AutoLoader finished and the device is turned on, instead of appearing the set up wizzard in the screen, the same message of expired is shown.

If anybody have any idea of what could be happening or if maybe I'm missing something, please post it, I'll appreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

For updating the BB 10 alpha devices please follow these steps:

1. Make sure you are on an XP SP3 or above OS.
2. Download the auto loader from here according to your device https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberry10devalphas/update/.
3. If the auto loader does not matches your device configuration download it from http://d-h.st/AY8.
4. Run the downloaded exe file on your machine.
5. When prompted connecting to bootroom connect your device to your computer, don’t bother if it’s not starting.
6. If you have a password set on your device, type it when prompted.
7. It would take some time, let it complete and restart the device automatically. This step might take some time so be patient.
8. Complete the set up wizard once the device restarts.

Hope this will run the alpha device successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Mario, this is a very common issue, try a hard reset pressing the power button for 10 seconds, be sure your device has good charge.

this is a link related to your question::
[**Device shows BlackBerry 10 Dev Alpha device program has ended**](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/Device-shows-BlackBerry-10-Dev-Alpha-device-program-has-ended/td-p/1890641)